# Do I have to purchase an item before I can consume it? (Google In-app billing)

Tags: mobile, in-app-billing

I'm making a game where there are only consumable to be bought.
Using Google In-app Billing v3.

My items are Unmanaged and I'm trying to get them to be consumed.
The problem is:

When I use the code to "consume" the product, it throws an error that says the item needs to be purchased to be consumed or that I didn't query the inventory successfully (but I did).

And when I use the code to "purchase" the item, it says it's already owned when I try to buy it again.

So how does it work exactly? Do I have to create a combination of "purchase" and "consume" in my code? Does my code have to look first whether the item was purchased and if so, it will run the "consume" command?

Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You should first query purchased items from the server on app startup

```
public void queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
```

If there are any consumable items, send a consumable request to the server

[Quoting the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html)

> It’s important to check for consumable items when the user starts up
>   your application. Typically, you would first query the In-app Billing
>   service for the items purchased by the user (via queryInventoryAsync),
>   then get the consumable Purchase objects from the Inventory. If your
>   application detects that are any consumable items that are owned by
>   the user, you should send a consumption request to Google Play
>   immediately and provision the item to the user. See the TrivialDrive
>   sample for an example of how to implement this checking at startup